# Append integer to global list inside function haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, append

I'll use a simple example for what I'm trying to do.

Say I have the list:

```
nums = []
```

Now I have the function:

```
allNums n = nums.append(n)
```

So if I run the function:

```
allNums 6
```

The list nums should have the values

```
[6]
```

I know nums.append doesn't work, but what code could replace that.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits that turned this into a completely different question about primes and factors. If you got a satisfactory answer to your question about appending to global lists, and now have a new question about primes, please just ask a new question. Editing the original question makes all the existing comments and answers to it look out of place and confusing to future readers.

Answer (score 4):

### Simple Answer:

You can't do that. Haskell is a pure, functional language, that means:

- A function does not have any side effect.
- A function does always return the same result when called with the same parameters.
- A function may or may not be called, but you don't have to care about that. If it wasn't called, it wasn't needed, but because the function does not have any side effects, you won't find out.

### Complex answer:

You could use the State Monad to implement something that behaves a bit like this, but this is probably out of reach for you yet.

Comment: Another answer: `MVar`s.  You technically can have a global mutable variable, but no beginner ever actually needs this functionality, it's really only for very specific and complex situations, and in my years of using Haskell I've never actually needed to use it.

Comment: I'm still a beginner to Haskell, and I've already seen some stuff you can do with some unsafe stuff, but IMHO this is usually a bad idea, there are reasons for it, but when you use it then do me a favor: Hide this fact so I don't have to care. But I've never heard about `MVar`s.

Comment: They're literally mutable variables, but in order to read or write to them you have to use IO actions.  They're very primitive objects, and they're safe to use but you have to worry about the details a lot more.  You don't have to resort to `unsafePerformIO` (don't ever use this unless you _really_ know what you're doing), but there's almost always a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting to use an **infinite list** instead of appending to global variable.
It's true haskell is pure functional. But also it's lazy. Every part of data is not calculated until is really needed. It also applies to collections. So you could even define a collection with elements based on previous elements of same collection.
Consider following code:

```
isPrime n = all (\p -> (n `mod` p) /= 0 ) $ takeWhile (\p ->p * p <= n) primes

primes = 2 : ( filter isPrime $ iterate (+1) 3 )

main = putStrLn $ show $ take 100 primes
```

definition of `isPrime` is trivia when primes list is defined. It takes pack of primes which is less or equivalent to square root of examining number

```
takeWhile (\p ->p * p <= n) primes
```

then it checks if number have only non-zero remainders in division by all of these numbers

```
all (\p -> (n `mod` p) /= 0 )
```

the `$` here is an [application operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-)

Next using this definition we taking all numbers starting from 3:

```
iterate (+1) 3
```

And filtering primes from them.

```
filter isPrime
```

Then we just prepending the first prime to it:

```
primes = 2 : ( ... )
```

So `primes` becomes an infinite self-referred list.

You may ask: why we prepending 2 and just no starting filtering numbers from it like:

```
primes = filter isPrime $ iterate (+1) 2
```

You could check this leads to [uncomputable expression](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) because the `isPrime` function needs at least one known member of `primes` to apply the `takeWhile` to it.

As you can see `primes` is well defined and immutable while it could have as many elements as you'll need in your logic.